# How to plot drawContours in openCV 4 with python

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am starting to get crazy with openCVs drawContours. Every time I run the Code, nothing shows up. Src image and contours are computed fine, but what am I doing wrong?

```
grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blurredImg = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayFrame,(5,5),0)

optimumThreshold, bw = cv2.threshold(blurredImg,120,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bw, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(bw, contours, 1, (153,0,0), 4)
```

Comment: can you provide some image?

Comment: Unfortunately not since the cv2.drawContour doesn‘t plot anything. Plotting the src image with command cv2.imageshow('name',bw) works fine. But regardless if I plot src before or afterwards the contours, the dont Show up in any plot (without cv2.imageshow('name',bw), there is not even a plotting window appearing at all).  Contour exraction works correct, I can plot them After some array Manipulation with matplotlib (which is sadly inappropriate for my usecase, so not an Option Instead of OpenCV). Any ideas? :/

Comment: Specifying the colour to draw with as `(153,0,0)` is a bit misleading, given that you're drawing into a single channel image. Seeing that I'd expect to see blue output, but in reality it will draw in gray. What sort of output are you actually expecting to see?

Comment: At least anything :D I changed contours colors to (153,0,0) rgb because the resulting color can be easily seen when plotted in grayscale. Would you recommend to plot in a colored src image? I still dont understand why not even a window for plotting opens up when running cv2.drawContours as single command ...